# How to extract from object based on value of a property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects, wanted to extract values based on the property

```
let obj = [
    {
      "name": "USA",
      "type": "Required",
    },
    {
      "name": "Australia",
      "type": "Discontinued",
    },
    {
      "name": "Austria",
      "type": "Optional",
    } ,
  {
      "name": "Argentina",
      "type": "Required",
    } 
]
```

I have tried to extract from that array of objects based on type like this,

```
let arr = obj.map((cc)=>{ if(cc["type"] == "Required"){
  return cc["type"]
} })
```

Now, I am getting result as, ["Required", undefined, undefined, "Required"]

But, I am expecting array containing only ["Required", "Required"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `filter` followed by `map`, as demonstrated in the other answers:

```
let arr = obj.filter(cc => cc.type=="Required").map(cc => cc.type);
```

or the other way round, since your condition is based on the map result anyway:

```
let arr = obj.map(cc => cc.type).filter(val => val=="Required");
```

But if you want to do it in one step, I would recommend `flatMap` :

```
let arr = obj.flatMap(cc => cc.type=="Required" ? [cc.type] : []);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I have tried the second solution and it worked, Is there any way I check based on two types, Like, `let arr = obj.map((cc)=>{ 
  return cc["type"]
 }).filter(type => type=="Required" && type == "Optional") `

Comment: @srikanth You will probably want to use `||` instead of `&&`. A value cannot be equal to both `"Required"` and `"Optional"` at the same time :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use filter with map

```
let arr = obj.filter((cc)=> cc["type"] == "Required").map( cc => cc.type);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to iterate once then you could make use of `reduce`:

```
obj.reduce((a, e) => e.type === 'Required' ? a.concat(e.type) : a, [])
```